# Example of subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ that is not a 2-interval.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have come to an exercise in a multivariable calculus textbook that I'm having trouble finding an answer to. First I'll start with some definitions within the text of the book. Define two arbitrary vectors $\boldsymbol{a},\boldsymbol{b} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. We also write the vectors out as $\boldsymbol{a} = (a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{n})$ and $\boldsymbol{b}=(b_{1},b_{2},...,b_{n})$. Then we define a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ $\boldsymbol{I}_{\boldsymbol{a},\boldsymbol{b}}$ as :
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{I}_{\boldsymbol{a},\boldsymbol{b}} = I_{a_{1},b_{1}} \times \dots \times I_{a_{n},b_{n}}
\end{equation}
Where each $I_{a_{i},b_{i}}$ is the closed interval on the real line $[a_{i},b_{i}]$.

Now they define an n-interval as a subset $I$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that
$\boldsymbol{I}_{\boldsymbol{a},\boldsymbol{b}} \subseteq I$ for every
$\boldsymbol{a},\boldsymbol{b} \in I$.

They also define a partial order relation on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ denoted $\leq$ with definition :
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{a} \leq \boldsymbol{b} \Leftrightarrow a_{i} \leq b_{i} \; \forall i \in \{1,2,...,n\}
\end{equation}

Now I'll describe the question in the exercise.

"Give an example of a subset $D$ of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that $D$ is not a 2-interval, but
$D$ has the property that $\boldsymbol{I}_{\boldsymbol{a},\boldsymbol{b}} \subseteq D$ for
every $\boldsymbol{a},\boldsymbol{b} \in D$ with $\boldsymbol{a} \leq \boldsymbol{b}$."

Can someone help find an example that meets the requirements of the problem ?

Comment: Ordinarily, I'd understand $[a_i,b_i]$ to be empty if $a_i>b_i$. But then $I_{a,b}=\emptyset$ when $a\not\leq b$ and no such $D$ will exist. Is the source of this problem using a different meaning for $[a_i,b_i]$? Or am I just missing something?

Comment: I think in the book if $b_{i} < a_{i}$ then $[a_{i},b_{i}] = [b_{i},a_{i}]$.

Comment: Then take  $D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:x+y\geq1\}$.  For $a=(1,0)$ and $b=(0,1)$, you have $I_{a,b}=[0,1]\times[0,1]$, which contains $(0,0)$, which isn't in $D$. So $D$ is not a $2$-interval. But $D$ has the required property that, whenever $a'\leq b'$ are both in $D$, then $D$ contains $I_{a',b'}$.